# How To Show/Hide WordPress Meta Boxes Fields According to Option Select

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, meta-boxes

I have a select list with values `hosts` and `html5` and 3 custom fields. On select with value `hosts` 2 fields (Youtube and Vimeo) should appear, and if value is `html5` the remain (Embed) should appear.

```
array(
    'name'     => __( 'Video File Host', 'suarezthemelocal' ),
    'id'       => 'videohost',
    'desc' => __( 'Select host of your video file. <br> <strong>Note:</strong> If you couldn\'t find host of your video file in the dropdown list, you can paste the embed code of file in the "Video Embed Code" box.', 'rwmb' ),
    'type'     => 'select',
    // Array of 'value' => 'Label' pairs for select box
    'options'  => array(
        'host' => __( 'Video Hosts', 'suarezthemelocal' ),
        'html5' => __( 'HTML5 Video', 'suarezthemelocal' ),
    ),
    // Select multiple values, optional. Default is false.
    'multiple'    => false,
    'std'         => '',
    'placeholder' => __( 'Select an Item', 'suarezthemelocal' ),
),
array(
    'name' => __('Youtube Video ID','suarezthemelocal'),
    'id' => 'video_youtube_id',
    'type' => 'text',
    'std' => '',
    'desc' => __('Youtube video ID','suarezthemelocal')
),
array(
    'name' => __('Vimeo Video ID','suarezthemelocal'),
    'id' => 'video_vimeo_id',
    'type' => 'text',
    'std' => '',
    'desc' => __('Vimeo video ID','suarezthemelocal')
),
array(
    'name' => __('Video Embed Code','suarezthemelocal'),
    'id' => 'video_embed_code',
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'std' => '',
    'desc' => __('Video Embed code. You can grab embed codes from hosted video sites.','suarezthemelocal')
)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Now that you have the meta boxes added, you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I know this but how can I hide or appear more fields at one time. Can I add class to each type to archive this?

Comment: The already have IDs assigned to them. You should be able to target them that way.

Comment: Yes, I already tried and it works also, but if I have more than 2 fields I have to enter more ID. Do you have any uselful way? Thank you.